# Caching architecture advise for a specific scenario

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, caching, architecture

### SETUP:

We have a .Net application that is distributed over 6 local servers each with a local database(ORACLE), 1 main server and 1 load balance machine. Requests come to the load balancer which redirects the incoming requests to one of the 6 local servers. In certain time intervals data is gathered in the main server and redistributed to the 6 local servers to be able to make decisions with the complete data.

Each local server has a cache component that caches the incoming requests based on different parameters (Location, incoming parameters, etc). With each request a local server decides whether to go to the database (ORACLE) or get the response from the cache. However in both cases the local server has to goto the database to do 1 insert and 1 update per request.

### PROBLEM:

On a peak day each local server receives 2000 requests per second and system starts slowing down (CPU: 90% ). I am trying to increase the capacity before adding another local server to the mix. After running some benchmarks the bottleneck as it always is, seems to be the inevitable 1 insert and 1 update per request to database.

### TRIED METHODS

To be able decrease the frequency I have created a Windows service that sits between the DB and .NET application. It contains a pipe server and receives each insert and update from the main .NET application and saves them in a Hashtable. The new service then at certain time intervals goes to the database once to do batch inserts and updates. The point was to go to the database less frequently. Although this had a positive effect it didn't benefit to the system load as much as I expected. The most of the cpu load comes from oracle.exe as requests per second increase.

I am trying to avoid going to the database as much as I can and the only way to avoid DB seems to be increasing the cache hit ratio other than the above mentioned solution I tried. My cache hit ratio is around 81 % percent currently. Because each local machine has its own cache I am actually missing lots of cacheable requests. When two similar requests redirects to different servers the second request cannot benefit from the cached result of the first one.

I don't have a lot of experience in system architecture so I would appreciate any help to this problem. Any suggestions on different caching architectures or setup, or any tools are welcome.

Thank you in advance, hopefully I made my question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is old now, but I wanted let everyone know how we solved our issue.

After trying many optimizations it turned out that all we needed was Solid State Drives for the 6 local machines. The CPU dropped down to 30% percent immediately after we installed them. This is the first time that I've seen any kind of hardware update contributes this much to performance.

If you have high load setup, before making any software or architecture changes try upgrading to a SSD.

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

For me this looks like a application for a timesten solution. In that case you can eliminate the local databases and return to just one. Where you now have the local oracle databases, you can implement a cache grid. Most likely this is going to be a AWT (Async, Write Through) cache. See [Oracle In-Memory Database Cache Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e13073/concepts.htm#BABFBIEC)
It's not a cheap option but if could be worth investigating.
You can keep concentrating on the business logic and have no worries about speed. This of course only works good, if the aplication code is already tuned and the sql is performant and scalable. The SQL has to be prepared (using bind variables) to have the best performance.
Your application connects to the cache and no longer to the database. You create the cache tables in the cache group for which you want to have caching. All tables in a SQL should be cached, otherwise, the complete SQL is passed through to the Oracle database. In the grid a cache fusion mechanism is in place so you have no worries about where the data in your grid is located.
In the current release support for .net is included.
The data is consistent and asynchronously updated to the Oracle database. If the data that is needed is in the cache and you take the Oracle database down, the app can keep running. As soon as the database is back again, the synchronization pick up again. Very powerful.

Comment: It looks like a big implementation change but well worth investigating. So if you have to scale horizontally, you would just add new cache to the grid?

Answer (score 1):

2000 requests per second per server, about 24000 rps to database. It's a HUGE load for DB.
Try to optimize, scaleup or clusterize database.

May be NoSQL DB (Redis\Raven\Mongo) as middleware will be suitable for you. Local server will read\write sharded NoSQL DB, aggregated data will by synchronized with Oracle off-peak times.

Comment: Actually each server has its own database so it is more like 4000 rps per server without the middleware I mentioned in the tried methods section. I edited the question to make those parts more clear. NoSQL maybe a good solution however the problem is we cannot wait too much to synchronize the data because the live statistics are used in the business layer. The time interval to synchronize data is 2 seconds max for the needs of the application.

Comment: Live Statistics + High Load = Need to scale database.

Comment: Yes probably we will have to add one more server to the mix. I am just trying to understand if we have the most optimized structure for an application like this.

Comment: Facebook performance is about half of maximum, Twitter may be 10 times slower than may be (because of Ruby). But who cares? It works, it makes money. Optimizing whole architecture can produce bugs and limitations. You find bottleneck - database, fight THIS bottleneck.